# SMS retriever api android not working in vivo v15 pro, redmi note 4

Tags: android, kotlin, sms-retriever-api

I have successfully implemented SMS retriever in my application using the guideline [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request) . My Code is working fine and otp is auto populated in many devices but some of the devices like vivo v15 pro, redmi note 4 it is not working (BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() not get triggered) . i have attached my code here. check and let me know if you have any solution for this. Thanks

Manifest.xml

```
     <receiver
            android:name=".sms.SMSRetrieverBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

SMSRetrieverBroadcastReceiver.kt

```
   class SMSRetrieverBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {



companion object{
    private var otpReceiver: OtpReceiver? = null
    fun initOTPListener(receiver: OtpReceiver) {
        this.otpReceiver = receiver
    }
}

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION == intent.action) {
        val extras = intent.extras
        val status = extras!!.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

        when (status.statusCode) {
            CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                // Get SMS message contents
                var otp: String = extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE) as String
                Timber.d("OTP_Message "+otp)
              if(otpReceiver != null) {
                    otpReceiver!!.onOTPReceived(otp)
                }
            }

            CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                // Waiting for SMS timed out (5 minutes)
                // Handle the error ...
                if(otpReceiver != null) {
                    otpReceiver!!.onOTPTimeOut()
                }
        }
    }
}}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
fun startListeningForSMS() {
    SMSRetrieverBroadcastReceiver.initOTPListener(this)
    startSmsListener()
}


private fun startSmsListener() {
    val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(mContext)
    val task = client.startSmsRetriever()
    task.addOnSuccessListener {
        Timber.d("Success")
    }

    task.addOnFailureListener {
        Timber.d("Failed")
    }
}

override fun onOTPReceived(otp: String) {
    setReceivedOtp(otp)
}

override fun onOTPTimeOut() {
    setReceivedOtp(null)
}
```

Comment: `but some of the devices like vivo v15 pro, redmi note 4 it is not working` do you mean that it doesn't get populated or does it mean that it crashes or... ?  maybe you should just clarify this in your question :)

Comment: Broadcast receiver is not even triggered in those devices.

Comment: Yes and it is prevalent in a lot of devices.

Comment: Some devices requires you to go to either Settings > App > Permission, or Security > Permissions > Autostart to enable the required permission. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes tried that also. still auto populate is not working :(

Comment: Have you register the broadcast receiver in the activity.

Comment: Yes. if i hadnt it wont populate in any devices. its giving issues only some of the devices

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Same thing is happening for SMS User Consent too.

Comment: @MathanG Any updates on this?

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati Did you find any solution?

Comment: @abbujan So far no, but in my case, I think the issue is somewhere else. I set up a new dummy app and added consent to it, and it is working fine. This means that my old app shouldn't have worked in all devices, but working fine in most except for Redmi. Even working in Vivo in my case.

Comment: I'm currently bisecting the git commits to find if there is any specific commit which broke the feature for Redmi devices. Will update if I find anything.

Comment: Check if Google Play Services is greater than 18.7.13

Comment: @MathanG Any solution found?

Comment: @HardikAmal unfortunately no.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Messeges-click on (:) on top left ->Go to setting->Disable prevention from Otp verification.It worked fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with this intent-filter action:

```
 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```